Cannibal movie with a scene where a guy's wrist has been cut and gets eaten by ants
It is an old cannibal movie. There's a guy cutting the wrist of another guy and tying his arms so the ants can eat it. The next day, they saw the guy dead with just bones on his wrist.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Are there any science fiction or fantasy elements in this movie?  It has to be on-topic to ask about it here.

If not, you could ask on Film/Movies (whatever it’s called) SE, it may be on topic there.
